# DOCTYPE breaks css background-color

Tags: html, css, background-color, doctype

I recently added DOCTYPE to a page, but this caused some table cell formatting to break.   When the page loads, the cell should appear with a green background.

[Here's what's happening](http://jsfiddle.net/96SrB/) (fiddle)

Note the page loads without the green background as specified in the inline style tag.  If I hover over, the style goes into effect and remains.

The page should load with the background color properly rendered (without having to mouseover to initiate it).

I can't show the working example because JSFiddle includes DOCTYPE on their page.  If I remove the DOCTYPE line, the css works as expected.

Here's the code, with DOCTYPE line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    <body>
    <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr style=" background-color:#FFFEF7; ">
        <td style="color:FFFFFF; background-color:009C00;" title="It's Hard Being Green" onmouseover="this.style.background='#40b540'; this.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#009C00';">It's Hard Being Green</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you choose http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd?

Comment: Probably unrelated but you're missing a `</head>` tag in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `#` to the color declarations:

```
<tr style=" background-color:#FFFEF7; ">
        <td style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#009C00;" ...
```

Comment: That's it.  Thanks, will mark as accepted answer when the 7 minutes has expired.